# Android : programatically add id to an actionbar item

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

i m trying to set an id to an item of the actionbarsherlock, but i'm getting this "Cannot invoke setId(int) on the primitive type void"

```
    menu.add("new")
        .setIcon(R.drawable.icon_1)
        .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM)
        .setId(R.id.newone);
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have two problems, one [`setShowAsAction`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html#setShowAsAction%28int%29) returns `void`, so you cannot chain another call on it.

Second, `MenuItem` has no `setID` method.  You cannot change the id after the item is created.  To set an ID, you have to do it in the [`add` method] from `Menu`[2](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Menu.html#add%28int,%20int,%20int,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29),

```
menu.add("new", myItemId, myOrder, "TEXT" )
        .setIcon(R.drawable.icon_1, )
        .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);
```

Comment: The first parameter for the .add() method is an int groupID not a string.